# Glass: setText size limitation ? How to display full screen text

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I've just updated my glasses to XE12. Since then the Card doesn't behave in the same way as before.

I want to display a card of text. Here is my current code, I had to change "setFullScreenImages" by "setImageLayout()" as it was deprecated.

```
card = new Card(this);
card.setText("Ce chocolat contient :\nSucre, beurre de cacao, cacao (min 31.5%), lait en poudre entier, liqueur de cacao, lécithine, vanilline.");
card.setImageLayout(ImageLayout.FULL);
card.addImage(R.drawable.card_chocolate_background);
card.setFootnote("Info produit");
```

The result I got with XE11 was:
[image: XE11 result]

The result with XE12:
[image: XE12 result]

Can someone tell me how to display the text correctly ? I have a demo tomorrow and I'm a bit stucked with this autoupdate.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was indeed a change in the full-screen image layout in XE12, to match other card styles used on Glass.

If you're just using the `Card` to generate views, you can duplicate the old look with a custom layout for the time being. If you need it to insert static cards, on the other hand, you'll either need to use the new layout or switch to `ImageLayout.LEFT` to fit some more text on the card. You may want to follow [issue 315](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=315) on our issue tracker, since it sounds like that functionality would help you with creating more customized layouts.

Comment: I assume this is temporary measure, so we'll get a better support on XE13 then?